# Custom Log file not being fetched in Rails production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this custom logger with custom log file that is being called in some part in my code..

```
class MyCustomLogger

  def initialize(message={})
    @message = message
  end

  def send_to_log_file
    logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new(Rails.root.join('log/recommended_profiles.log'))
    logger.info "Job ID: #{@message[:job_id]} | Profile ID: #{@message[:profile]} | User ID: #{@message[:user_id]}"
  end

end
```

I have my `log/recommended_profiles.log` file in my production server. But I'm getting this error:

```
 Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - 

 /data/prod/releases/20150701071135/log/recommended_profiles.log
```

How to override to use only just that file? Ignoring time stamps?

UPDATE:

I'm using unicorn and I have this current path that I would like to call `current_path = '/data/prod/current'` . But it reads the releases folder instead.

Comment: Does `../log/recommended_profiles.log` work?

Comment: there's a `Rails.root` already?

Comment: Try `Rails.root.join('../log/recommended_profiles.log')`.

Comment: Does the `log` folder exist on your production environment?

Comment: I'm using unicorn and I have this current path that I would like to call `current_path = '/data/prod/current'` . But it reads the `releases` folder instead.